Сложный запрос фильтрации выручки по типам оплаты
Помогите, пожалуйста, с задачей. Нужно сделать фильтрацию выручки по типам оплаты. Выручка считается по чекам в таблице check. С чеками связаны транзакции, в которых хранится информация об оплате (также стоимость чека хранится в самом чеке). Транзакции могут быть разных типов (наличные, безналичные и так далее). Транзакции хранятся в таблице pay_transaction, тип транзакции - в таблице payment_type.
Считать выручку мешают смешанные чеки. Смешанные чеки - это чеки, оплаченные несколькими видами оплаты. Например, наличными и безналичными. Для таких чеков создаются несколько транзакций разных типов. Чтобы определить тип чека (смешанный или простой) я считаю количество транзакций разных типов. Если это число больше, то чек смешанный.
Но смешанных чеков в природе не существует. Это просто чеки, оплаченные разными видами оплаты. И наличная и безналичная части этого чека должны идти в соответствующие категории выручки (в категорий налички или безналичного расчета). Как это можно сделать?
Я придумал для простых чеков считать выручку на основании полей check.total_with_discount и check.total. Это правильно. Но со смешанными чеками все сложнее. При подсчете, например, выручки наличными, нельзя просто взять и прибавить стоимость смешанного чека, потому что она общая. Нужно взять из транзакции нужного типа (наличка) количество оплаты и присуммировать к общей выручке.
Как это можно реализовать? Я уже запутался. Логика сложная. Мешает то, что при джойне таблиц с транзакциями строки с чеками дублируются и их приходится группировать, чтобы удалить дубликаты. С агрегаций и группировкой в этой запросе вообще проблемы.
Запрос выглядит так:
 with all_checks as (
    select c.id as id, 
           count(distinct pt.id) > 1 as mixed, 
           sum(tx.sum) as tx_sum 
    from `check` c
    join pay_transaction tx on c.id = tx.order_check_id
    join payment_type pt on tx.type_id = pt.id
    join posinfo pi on c.id_pos = pi.id
    where c.status = 7
        and c.id_pos = 745
        and id_brand = 24
        and c.time between '2024-12-01 00:00:00' and '2024-12-01 23:59:59'
        and pt.name_type = 'Наличные'
    group by c.id
)
    SELECT SUM(IF(t.mixed = false, IF(t.total_with_sale != 0, t.total_with_sale, t.total), t.tx_sum)) as total
    FROM (
        SELECT total_with_sale, total, mixed, tx_sum
        FROM `check` c
        JOIN all_checks ac on c.id = ac.id
        join pay_transaction tx on c.id = tx.order_check_id
        join payment_type pt on tx.type_id = pt.id
        WHERE pt.name_type = 'Наличные'
        GROUP BY c.id
      ) as t;


Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? Читаете внимательно пункты 5 и 3 (и 2.3), создаёте адекватную модель (на 5-10 записей, все вариации, поля, лишние для алгоритма, убрать) и выкладываете. Тогда будет предмет для разговора.

Я не понимаю, зачем считать сумму по чекам, а не по транзакциям. Неужели у вас возможно рассогласование?

@Akina проблема в том, что транзакции починили только 1 декабря. А считать отчет надо за прошлые периоды, а там транзакции битые

Не, погодите... Если сумма транзакций бьётся по чеку - можно считать и по транзакциям. А если не бьётся - то у вас просто нет информации о том, сколько денег из чека отслюнявить в наличку, а сколько оставить безналу. То есть хоть на пупе извернись, а надёжно сумму посчитать нельзя, хоть так, хоть эдак. Чек на стольник, тридцатка наличные, полста безналом, и как определить, куда оставшуюся двадцатку?

@typemoon А в чем "битость" транзакций заключалась, там вообще нет записей или они есть, но в них что то не корректное. Если не корректное то что. Ну т.е. насколько можно вообще доверять цифрам с транзакций. Вдруг вы транзакции найдете, их будет несколько, но суммы с них брать нельзя

@Mike вот, например, с одним чеком связана транзакция - получения наличных 5000. А транзакция для возврата сдачи не создалась из-за ошибки в системе. Если мы будем считать выручку по таким транзакциям, то она будет неправильная, потому что посчитается эта 5000 рублей, а то, что с этих денег давали сдачу - в системе не зафиксировано. Просто систему писали без строгого ТЗ, а потом началась текучка кадров и все это привело к тому, что система работает криво

У вас есть чек и транзакции к нему. Если суммы совпадают - считаете итоги по каждому чеку по видам оплаты. Если суммы не совпадают, разницу относите на отдельную категорию видов оплат "ошибки и пропуски".

Ну и если что Akina правильно примерную схему БД просил, по запросу многие поля не понятно даже в какой таблице, алиасы не везде стоят. И учитывая, что надо сравнивать по предложению ValNik общую сумму с разбивкой и потом и на выходе эту же разбивку сохранять, то тут оконные функции бы сильно помогли. А если так, то хорошо бы знать версию MySQL

И как вариант не этот запрос корежить, а потом еще какие нибудь другие запросы. И всегда помнить что вот такая проблема была и поэтому делам кучу костылей. А привести БД в нормальное состояние, т.е. добавить записи транзакций с каким то особым типом "ошибки и пропуски" или с существующим типом "возврат сдачи" (если только их забыли) на все чеки для которых сумма по чеку не совпадает с суммой транзакций

Вы ищете сумму по name_type = 'Наличные'. Много ли у вас этих типов? Может посчитать все а потом разобраться с итогом по счету?
